# Is there any version control tool for ksqldb queries?

Tags: ksqldb

I'm new to ksqldb, and I’m looking for a version control tool for ksqldb like flyway migrations for RDMBS in java.

I read the page below and understand the way of upgrading queries, but I'd like to operate to control versions of streams and tables more systematically.
https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/concepts/upgrades/

Maybe there is no tools to meet this kind of requirements so far, and I just need to develop by myself?
or is any projects for this ongoing?

Answer (score 0):

From ksqldb 0.17.0, we can use a version control tool!

> The ksql-migrations tool is available with all ksqlDB versions starting from ksqlDB 0.17 or Confluent Platform 6.2. You can use the tool to manage any ksqlDB cluster running version ksqlDB 0.10 (Confluent Platform 6.0) or newer.

For details, please refer the [ksqldb's document](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/migrations-tool/).

- Announcement
  https://www.confluent.io/blog/announcing-ksqldb-0-17-0-new-features-and-updates/#version-control